# Linux application to receive a constant stream of data, parse, and output text

Tags: linux

I'm wondering how to go about creating <strike>an application</strike> a set of commands, maybe contained in a shell script, which:

- receives a constant stream of binary data (from a weather station attached to a serial port, if you're wondering),
- identifies a pattern (e.g. this byte is `0x9F`, so the next 33 bytes are temperature data),
- parses the data (e.g. three bits of the low nibble of byte 2 combine with the high nibble and low nibble of byte 1 to represent temperature in °C),
- and outputs text (e.g. `t0 350` where `t0` is just a sensor id and `350` is the temperature in 1/10 °C)

The environment is linux (debian, 2.6.32-5-kirkwood), within which I am only a beginner.

I imagine that there is an idiomatic way of doing this sort of thing in linux. I'm willing to learn the tools necessary if one could point me down the right track. In particular, I'm wondering how to handle bitwise manipulations (unless I use `C++`) and a constant input stream.

Ideally, the amount of code I would write would be small compared to using existing linux commands/libraries.

I would prefer not to use Mono, despite the fact that I know C# very well, simply because I have to build mono on the device (which is a SheevaPlug) which takes a long time and is error prone (for me). Also, I haven't figured out cross-compiling for the plug.

(It's a plugin to allow [meteohub](http://wiki.meteohub.de/Introduction) to log data from a WM918/WX200 weather station, if you're curious.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core philosophy of any Unix/Linux system is that "everything is a file". So the serial port you've hooked the weather station up to will be represented by a device file in the `/dev/` directory. You can read from it using the standard fopen/fread/fclose type functions that most any language supports.

From that point on, it's just a matter of doing whatever processing with the data stream.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `(stty raw; cat > received.bin) < /dev/ttyUSB0` except instead of having the output of the serial port go to a file, it would go to my application. That way the app is simply a parser. Using built-in commands like `stty` is what I meant by an 'idiomatic' linux solution to this problem. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

Because I always do things the hard way, I would write a 20-line C program to do this task:

1. fopen( ) the weather-data input serial device; fopen( ) output device, whatever it is;
2. loop forever on fread( ) that weather-data serial device;
3. do bitwise/bytewise weather-data manipulation;
4. fwrite( ) output device;
5. end of loop forever

Yes, you could write a shell script to do some of that, but I think you are going to have to code at least the bit/byte-manipulation part.

-- pete

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that I would have to code the bit manipulation stuff in C/C++/Python. I just starting learning `awk`, but its bitwise manipulators are harder to grok for me.